Javascript Fetch using POST always returns status 400
Just following all the examples in ChatGTP and Google but my first use of javascript fetch with POST always returns 400. (I have a fetch using GET which works fine so I don't understand why POST fails.)
Here is the Fetch javascript code:
async function FetchPost() {
    let data = { a: 1, b: 2 };
    let json = JSON.stringify(data);
    try {
        const response = await fetch('/FetchDemo?handler=Fetch',
            {
                method: 'POST',
                // adding mode, cache and credentials did not help
                mode: 'cors', 
                cache: 'no-cache', 
                credentials: 'same-origin', 
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: json
            });

        if (response.ok) {
            data = await response.json();
        } else {
            throw new exception(response.statusText);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        data = 'Error fetching data:' + error;
    }
    return data;
}

Here is the OnGet (which works) and the OnPost method but it is never executed. The Network log in the browser shows the 400 status.
public class FetchDemoModel : PageModel {
    public void OnGet() {
    }
    // This always works
    public IActionResult OnGetFetch(string action, string identity) {
        string data = "";
        switch(action.ToLower()) {
            case "find":
                break;
            default:
                data = "action=" + action + ", identity=" + identity; 
                break;
        }
        return new JsonResult(data);
    }
    // This code is never executed
    public IActionResult OnPostFetch() {
        string data = "";
        return new JsonResult(data);
    }
}

For completeness and comparison here is the javascript fetch GET which works.
async function FetchGet(action, identity) {
    let data = null;
    try {
        let url = '/FetchDemo?handler=Fetch&action=' + action + "&identity=" + identity;
        const response = await fetch(url,
        {
            method: 'GET',
        });

        if (response.ok) {
            data = await response.json();
        } else {
            throw new exception(response.statusText);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        data = 'Error fetching data:' + error;
    }
    return data;
}

I have checked all the issues which ChatGPT says may cause a 400 error to no avail. Can you help diagnose this?

Is this client-side or server-side?  If it is server side, why are you doing a fetch at all?

Looks like some kind of asp.net server but I'm not familiar with those OnGetFetch and OnGetPost methods. How are the requests routed to those?

Could it be something simple like you're sending a body in the POST, but the server doesn't seem to expect any body, at least not that you seem to show in the code you posted?

A POST request from the browser client requires that there is a corresponding POST handler on the server.

400 Bad Request - could mean that you've used POST when server only accepts GET.  Or could mean the post parameters are not as expected.

Quick google finds zero matches for "OnPostFetch" so this looks like it's custom to your code - so maybe you have routing to "OnGetFetch" but not "OnPostFetch".

What happens if you remove/comment out the OnGet/OnGetFetch?  Would not be surprised if you then get a 404 (or a 500 if it breaks the routing, so comment that as well)

those are named handler methods for razor pages.. since it's called OnPostFetch I guess you need to pass a post parameter handler=Fetch like you did in the get request

Sorry for not explicitly mentioning this is an asp.net Razor page application and uses named handler methods.

The POST request is missing the required request verification token:

https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/336/ajax-posts-in-razor-pages-and-http-400-errors
https://www.learnrazorpages.com/security/request-verification

In short, you can either switch off request verification for the PageModel class by adding an IgnoreAntiforgeryToken attribute to it:
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken(Order = 10001)]
public class FetchDemoModel : PageModel
{
    ....

Or you can generate a hidden field using the Html.AntiForgeryToken helper in the view file and include it in the request headers:
var token = document.querySelector('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').value;
fetch(..., {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
        "RequestVerificationToken": token
    },
    body: { foo: "bar" }
}).then(() => {
    ...
});


There is nothing sweeter than waking up, checking your computer, and finding an answer to your issue! I probably spent 6 hours trying to solve this without success. I see now my main issue was not including the word RAZOR when I asked ChatGPT about status 400. Thanks Mike.
